# Google Maps API - Setting the Center on a Mobile Device

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api, google-maps-mobile

On a Mobile device we which to set the center of the map to the first coordinate, not the user's actual location as it does now.

So, for example:

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=49.34593,-123.1807&daddr=49.35037,-123.1749

Should center on 49.34593,-123.1807.

What paramaters can I use to have the map center on a mobile phone device.

Note: On a PC the center is as it should be. It's just on a mobile device that it centers on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-49.34, -123.18)
    // more options ....

  }
```